# Problems with Text Editor and Resizing Images - Quill

Tags: image, resize, quill

I'm trying to edit the size of images with a text editor. I'm using Quill text editor with Quill Field Form to save it to a database. I read some documentation and I can customize the tool bar through my settings.py file with this code...

```
    QUILL_CONFIGS = {
    'default':{
        'theme': 'snow',
        'modules': {
            'toolbar': [
                [
                    {'font': []},
                    {'header': []},
                    {'align': []},
                    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
                    {'color': []},
                    {'background': []},
                ],
                ['code-block', 'link'],
                ['clean'],
                ['link', 'image'],
            ],
            'imageResize': [],
        }
    }
}
```

I also did research and found that you can add something like this

```
imageResize: {
    displaySize: true
},
```

To the modules, part of the code in settings.py and you will be able to edit the size of the images which is my goal. When I do this though I get an error saying that imageResize is not recognized. I can do this when I have the similar code I have in settings.py in a script tag in my HTML code and then add the image size into modules and use the text editor that way. However, this does not work for me because I must save it to a database and the QuillForm is the easiest way.

My Final Question is how do I integrate something into the code I have in settings.py (that customizes the editor) to allow me to edit the size of images.

P.S. Sorry for my English